# Dependency Inject IModule and DirectoryModuleCatalog

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

Been Messing with Prism stuff, loading from libraries.

I have the following Library

```
namespace PersistenceXml
{
    [Module(ModuleName = "XmlContext", OnDemand = true)]
    public class XmlContext : IContext<XElement>, IModule
    {
        private readonly string fileName = @"Text.xml";
        public XElement Create()
        {
            return XElement.Load(fileName);
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have a WPF application in another project, implemented the following

```
namespace Presentation
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.TryResolve<MainWindow>();
        }
        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        protected override void InitializeModules()
        {
            base.InitializeModules();
        }
        protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            var c = new Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

And the xaml window

```
namespace Presentation
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

        public MainWindow(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Container = container;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var b = Container.IsRegistered(typeof(Interfaces.IContext<XElement>), "XmlContext");
            int i = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i place my PersistenceXml.dll in the Modules directory so Presentation can load it.
In Bootstrapper.CreateModuleCatalog i can see it has loaded 1 item. my module.
however in MainWindow i get false when i attempt to see if XmlContext is registered.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks
G.

UPDATE:

Changed the PersistenceXml Library around. Now have a class call Persistence that implements IModule. Persistence constructor has IUnityContainer injected. Initialize performs container registration of any other classes in PersistenceXml.

```
namespace PersistenceXml
{
    [Module(ModuleName = "Persistence", OnDemand = true)]
    public class Persistence : IModule
    {
        private IUnityContainer container;
        public Persistence(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            container.RegisterType<IContext<XElement>, XmlContext>    ("XmlContext");
        }
    }
}


namespace PersistenceXml
{  
    public class XmlContext : IContext<XElement>
    {
        private readonly string fileName = @"Text.xml";
        public XElement Create()
        {
            return XElement.Load(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Still somthing not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

XMLContext is not registered as `IContext<Element>` unless you register it.

Comment: I thought i might be able to do something like provide a constructor in XmlContext that takes a IUnityContainer. store in local variable. Then in XmlContext.Initialize do. container.RegisterType<IContext<XElement>, XmlContext>("XmlContext"); but that did not make much difference.

Comment: I also thought that defining a class that implements IModule and loading the dll with DirectoryModuleCatalog would have registered IContext<XElement>. but I guess I'm missing something still.

Comment: The ModuleCatalog does no registering with the container

Comment: okay thanks. So this brings up an issue. I'm trying to be modular and have the ability to switch out the persistence library. How do i configure my container without project references that are unavailable until runtime?

Comment: Argha, i think i may have figured this out. brb

Answer (score 0):

See UPDATE above.

Correctly implementing IModule in a class inside the library that is injected with IUnityContainer and stored for later use. Configure library specific Container registration in the IModule Initialize method.

```
namespace PersistenceXml
{
    [Module(ModuleName = "Persistence", OnDemand = true)]
    public class Persistence : IModule
    {
        private IUnityContainer container;
        public Persistence(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
        container.RegisterType<IContext<XElement>, XmlContext>    ("XmlContext");
        }
    }
}
```